# Keras custom loss with one of the features used and a condition

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to make a custom function for the deviance in Keras. 
Deviance is calculated as : 2 * (log(yTrue) - log(yPred))

The problem here is that my yTrue values are rare event count and therefore often equal to 0, resulting in a -inf error.

The derivation of deviance for my specific case (poisson unscaled deviance) gives a solution to this :

- If yTrue = 0, then deviance is : 2 * D * yPred where D is a feature of my data.
- If yTrue !=0, then deviance is : 2 * D * (yTrue * ln(yTrue) - yTrue * ln(yPred) - yTrue + yPred

There is two problems here i encounter :

- I need to choose the function according to the value of yPred
- I also need to pass D as argument to the loss function

I made a first iteration of a loss function before derivating deviance, adding small values to yTrue when it is equal to 0 to prevent the -Inf. problems, but it gives wrong results for deviance so i have to change it.

```
def DevianceBis(y_true, y_pred):
y_pred = KB.maximum(y_pred, 0.0 + KB.epsilon()) #make sure ypred is positive or ln(-x) = NAN
return (KB.sqrt(KB.square( 2 * KB.log(y_true + KB.epsilon()) - KB.log(y_pred))))
```

I'd like to know how to pass the D values into the loss function and how to use an if statement in order to choose the correct expression to use.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

Tried this one but returns NaN

```
    def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true = data[:, 0]
        d = data[:, 1:]
        # condition
        mask = keras.backend.equal(y_true, 0) #i.e. y_true != 0
        mask = KB.cast(mask, KB.floatx())
        # returns 0 when y_true =0, 1 otherwise
        #calculate loss using d...
        loss_value = mask * (2 * d * y_pred) + (1-mask) * 2 * d * (y_true * KB.log(y_true) - y_true * KB.log(y_pred) - y_true + y_pred)
        return loss_value


    def baseline_model():
        # create model
        #building model
        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(5, input_dim = 26, activation = "relu"))
        #model.add(Dense(10, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation = "exponential"))
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='RMSProp')
        return model

model = baseline_model()
model.fit(data2, np.append(y2, d, axis = 1), epochs=1, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

EDIT 2 :

```
def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

    y_true = data[:, 0]
    d = data[:, 1:]
    # condition
    mask2 = keras.backend.not_equal(y_true, 0) #i.e. y_true != 0
    mask2 = KB.cast(mask2, KB.floatx())
    # returns 0 when y_true =0, 1 otherwise
    #calculate loss using d...
    loss_value = 2 * d * y_pred + mask2 * (2 * d * y_true * KB.log(y_true) + 2 * d * y_true * KB.log(y_pred) - 2 * d * y_true)
    return loss_value
```

EDIT 3 seems to be working without the logs (altough it isn't the result i am looking for) :

```
def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

    y_true = data[:, 0]
    d = data[:, 1]
    # condition
    mask2 = keras.backend.not_equal(y_true, 0) #i.e. y_true != 0
    mask2 = KB.cast(mask2, KB.floatx())
    # returns 0 when y_true =0, 1 otherwise
    #calculate loss using d...
    loss_value = 2 * d * y_pred #+ mask2 * (2 * d * y_true * KB.log(y_true) + 2 * d * y_true * KB.log(y_pred) - 2 * d * y_true)
    return loss_value


def baseline_model():
    # create model
    #building model
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, input_dim = 26, activation = "relu"))
    #model.add(Dense(10, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "exponential"))
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='RMSProp')
    return model

model = baseline_model()
model.fit(data2, np.append(y2, d, axis = 1), epochs=1, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

EDIT again :

```
def custom_loss3(data, y_pred):

    y_true = data[:, 0]
    d = data[:, 1]
    # condition
    loss_value = KB.switch(KB.greater(y_true, 0), 2 * d * y_pred, 2 * d * (y_true * KB.log(y_true + KB.epsilon()) - y_true * KB.log(y_pred + KB.epsilon()) - y_true + y_pred))
    return loss_value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the final answer ... after days i finally found how to do it.

```
def custom_loss3(data, y_pred):
        y_true = data[:, 0]
        d = data[:, 1]

        lnYTrue = KB.switch(KB.equal(y_true, 0), KB.zeros_like(y_true), KB.log(y_true))
        lnYPred = KB.switch(KB.equal(y_pred, 0), KB.zeros_like(y_pred), KB.log(y_pred))
        loss_value = 2 * d * (y_true * lnYTrue - y_true * lnYPred[:, 0] - y_true + y_pred[:, 0])
        return loss_value
```

Calculate the logs before the actual loss and give K.zeros_like instead of it if the value of y_true is 0. Also need to only take the first vector of y_pred since it will return a vector NxN and y_true will return Nx1.

Also had to delete values of d=0 in the data (they wern't of much use anyway).

Answer (score 2):

If the `D` is a feature on input vector, you can pad your label with extra `D` columns from input and write a custom loss. You can pass the extra prediction info w.r.t. your input as a numpy array like this

```
    def custom_loss(data, y_pred):

        y_true = data[:, 0]
        d = data[:, 1:]
        # condition
        mask = K.not_equal(y_true, 0) #i.e. y_true != 0
        # returns 0 when y_true =0, 1 otherwise
        #calculate loss using d...
        loss_value = mask*(2*d*y_pred) + mask*(2*d*(y_true*ln(y_true) - y_true*ln(y_pred) - y_true + y_pred)
        return loss_value


    def baseline_model():
        # create model
        i = Input(shape=(5,))
        x = Dense(5, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear')(i)
        o = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(x)
        model = Model(i, o)
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005))
        return model


    model.fit(X, np.append(Y_true, d, axis =1), batch_size = batch_size, epochs=90, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

#### EDIT:

I added the mask for the conditional statement. I am not exactly sure if it will work that way, or do you need to cast it to integer tensors; because the function returns a `bool`.

Comment: Thanks, i'll probably need to use this as an optimizer function as well, can I still pass the column with a numpy array like this in that case ?

Comment: Can't edit anymore : Just noticed your case already covered this .. thanks for the help ! If you know how to get to use a condition into this i'd be interested too :)

Comment: Try it out and let me know. I have only tested passing input features into the loss by appending; but not the condition. I would be interested as well to know if it works :)

Comment: I was thinking of using the mask with it's opposite, and a function like : loss = mask1*(f1) + mask2*(f2). For this i'd need to get the opposite of the mask, i'm still knew to tensors, can i get it using : mask2 = K.not_equal(mask1, 0) ? Anyway i'll try this out and give you feedback :) (if i can't end it today i won't be able to do it until a few days)

Comment: Opposite of the mask works as well, I think. I am off for 3 days as well. So take your time :)

Comment: I just edited with what i tried, doesn't seem to work as loss gives NaN :/

Comment: Maybe we need to break down the problem to debug where it is going wrong. Passing the extra data is tried and tested. Check if you can test out the mask for the condition in a simple test case, not in the loss. Maybe try to write a simple model with a simple loss function that returns the mask multiplied by `y_true` and check with binary `y_true` values.

Comment: So I tried out some things and noticed that the mask seemed to work properly, and the NaN values are coming as soon as i put logs into the loss. I'll post what i tried which gives me NaNs because of the logs (used only one mask). wondering if d = 0 values could cause problems ?

Comment: I think you should first try disabling logs in the loss. And if you think the 0 values are causing a problem, you can maybe try with the 2 masks as you mentioned before.

Comment: What do you mean disable them ? Try if it's working without them ? I tried and it seemed to work but i can't take them out the loss since they are part of the deviance (which is my metric)

Comment: Yes I mean without putting logs. Does it work perfectly if you don't add logs to the loss? If yes, then we can maybe look at how you are using the logs and try to fix that error.

Comment: I will post something i did without the logs that is working in a few minutes. I also deleted all rows with d = 0 without success. (it also works with the # after "+ mask2"

Comment: Is it possible to print exact values of mask ? I'm thinking that the conversion maybe gives 0.000001 instead of 0 which would make the mask uneffective at nullifying logs. (Yes i'm starting to desperate and look at weird solutions)

Comment: Yeah I will check the mask. But I am travelling today and can properly try it out tomorrow. Is it not possible to cast the mask in int rather than float.

Comment: I'm tried that amready but it gives me the error : Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'. My guess would be that I can't multiply an integer and a float together ?

Comment: So : New found ... Adding KB.epsilon() to logs will work. So the problem is clearly comming from the logs. Altough I am not sure it is good to give log(epsilon) to the data where y = 0, because of how log function behaves when confronted to small numbers

Comment: Does your `y_pred` gives a positive value always? A negative would give NaN. You can try to clip the loss value and print the result to check if it's going towards the + or - infinity.

Comment: Last layer is exponential do i don't think it can get negative, am i correct ?

Comment: Anyway since adding epsilon completely removes NaN's i don't think it gets below 0

Comment: Exponential is always positive. So that's sorted. Generally the loss value shows NaN when it's too high or too low...i.e. towards either infinity. So, if that is the case, clipping will show which way it's going. I might be missing other reasons as well.

Comment: Alright so i'm updating this before going to sleep : Used epsilon to prevent null values AND using switch now instead of a mask. It seems like this options give better results. I'll edit my post to show you the loss i came up with. If i can ask you one more thing : The exponential actication in the last layer gives me results between 0 and 1. Thing is that i'm predicting values between 0 and 2. What can in order to make the network do predictions in the right interval ? (i guess multiplying by 2 makes no sense)

Comment: For an `exponential` function, the domain is R, the range is (0;+∞). So, that should be okay, no?

Comment: Also, I know you have put in a lot of effort in this question and solving the problem; but the original question you asked has been answered and the solution works. I think this part should be a separate different question, and that also would attract new people towards the problem. If you agree, you can close this question by accepting my answer( or you can post your own solution and accept it), and write a new question about handling the log loss.

Comment: Indeed ! Yeah but my values seems to be kept withen [0,1]. Anyway thanks for the help i'll maybe post another question when i have more time to spare on this project :)

Comment: This problem is interesting and I will also try to find a solution to it.

Comment: If you are still interested in the problem, i solved most of the issues and i'm left with a last one (hope so) which i wrote a new question for, feel free to check it out when you have some spare time :)

Comment: Okay. Nice to hear that. Could you share the link of the new question? I will check when I get time.